# jquery append to already appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, append

Is it possible to append something to a div that was already appended? I tried but nothing happens.. (I'm not using linebreaks in the actual js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.add_text_input').click(function() {
        $('li').append('<div class="input_label">Untitled</div>\
                        <div class="edit_label"></div>\
                        <input type="text" name="untitled" /><br />');
    });

    $('.input_label').click(function() {    
        var input_label = $(this).html();   
        $(this).hide();
        $('.edit_label').append('<input type="text" name="untitled" value="' + input_label + '"/><br />');
    });

});
```

The js is for creating text inputs and editing their labels. When clicking on the "input_label" div, it should hide using hide() and append a text input with the default "untitled" value in the "edit_label" div. It works if the divs already exist but I need to make it work via append.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler here, like this:

```
$('.input_label').live('click', function() {
  var input_label = $(this).html();   
  $(this).hide().next('.edit_label')
    .append('<input type="text" name="untitled" value="' + input_label + '"/><br />');
});
```

This will work on elements regardless of when they're created, since it works off event bubbling, it'll work on any element's `click` event that matches the `.input_label` selector.

Currently with [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it's finding all the elements that exist at `document.ready` time and binding *to those elements*, not to the selector, so it won't work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: .live is deprecated